# Graph API - Returning 404 in certain data centers when accessing on-prem mailboxes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-404

I recently created a process that reads/writes contacts in users' mailboxes on-prem via Graph. This process works as expected most of the time but certain times it fails with a 404. I've narrowed it down to the datacenter Graph is using. I've verified nothing is causing this issue at the network perimeter and no API calls are actually reaching the Exchange servers when the 404 is returned.

404 - North Central US

```
DEBUG: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/zHM.Test%40fomain.com/contacts?$top=100
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
request-id: f245c3b7-4852-4494-aaf9-1424bfd9e41c
client-request-id: f245c3b7-4852-4494-aaf9-1424bfd9e41c
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central
US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_56"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: private
```

200 - East US

```
DEBUG: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/zHM.Test%40domain.com/contacts?$top=100
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
request-id: 2d014679-7c0c-4a68-bb3a-26e7cf91af53
client-request-id: 2d014679-7c0c-4a68-bb3a-26e7cf91af53
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East
US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_41"}}
OData-Version: 4.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: private
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2020 20:31:56 GMT
```

404 - North Europe

```
DEBUG: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/zHM.Test%40domain.com/contacts?$top=100
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
request-id: 4ddb30db-e9f7-4a20-bd46-d58d9226fc0b
client-request-id: 4ddb30db-e9f7-4a20-bd46-d58d9226fc0b
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North
Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"005","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_2"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: private
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2020 21:52:06 GMT
```

Comment: (1) I believe without the pagination ($top) you can repro the issue or not? (2) Is the issue intermittent or you can repro at will?

Comment: (3) Can you repro the issue outside of your code(using POSTMAN/Microsoft Graph Explorer) as well?

Comment: DEBUG: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user%40domain.com/contacts
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
request-id: f7386d40-7d84-4d7c-8e2f-429eeb18780f
client-request-id: f7386d40-7d84-4d7c-8e2f-429eeb18780f
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North
Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_69"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: private
Date: Thu, 26 Nov 2020 14:29:20 GMT

Comment: I can consistently reproduce the issue when doing it from our London site since it hits the 'North Europe' datacenter each time.

Comment: Cool... if you can able to isolate the issue outside of the code/your application, then you may want to consider opening support ticket with Microsoft support. So that they can investigate it further from Graph & datacenter perspective.

Comment: I can try, but they might push off because "hybrid is in preview".

Comment: hmm... in order to investigate datacenter related info, whether the API call is reaching the datacenter that's the way i forsee!! But let us know how it goes.

Comment: I just logged a case now, we'll see. Good thing is I can reproduce on demand and I can prove nothing is hitting on-prem during the issue. I've also seen at least two other threads posted with similar issues relating to Graph datacenter location.